# How to setup https with apache2

Tags: php, https, apache2

I had a question in mind that i have been fighting with a lot lately.

ok so i am trying to setup a HTTPs connection through my Apache2 server.  I am running a WAMP server atm.

I am not a system guy and i dont pocess great knowledge about HTTPs.

I know its a secure connection, and i want to learn how to set it up.

**So far i have done:**

Enabled openssl.dll in my PHP config file.

I checked the PHP headers with:

```
var_dump(stream_get_wrappers());
```

HTTPS is in the array :)

So im wondering what am i missing.

I want to tell that i read several onlien guideso n the subject, but there are some talks about

- RSA
- SSL

I am not sure how to use or set up those.

So in terms i am prob at step 1 out of 10 atm.

I am stuck.

What i want to do in the end is something like:

```
https://localhost/index.php
```

And if i try http instead i should be redirected to a https instead.

Any one can help me on this?

Comment: The best advice I can give you is a link to this awesome page I stumbled upon while struggling with exactly the same issue, http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/WampServer_HowTo.html#zz-5. Best of luck

Comment: The link above wont display correctly, look on the right hand side navigation, section 5 ssl

Comment: very nice link.  I will look at it :)

Comment: actually very very nice.  So many links online, this one rocks.  let me check it out.  Please make an answer so i can accept your reply.  Im very sure that this is the thing i ahave been looking for :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best guide I found while trying to set up ssl on a wamp server is this

http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/WampServer_HowTo.html#zz-5.

Comment: yes thats the thing.  I checked it out, its very nice.  Well written and all.  I need to wait 8 mins before i can accept your answer.

Comment: I cant upp your answer either, i need 15 reputation it tells me. meh hehe :)

Comment: No problem :) theres quite a few steps to it but if you follow it through carefully it will work, I used it myself.

Comment: Thanks again, smooth answer and quick solution.  :)   answer accepted